# Running git diff on added files via cherry picking

Tags: git, groovy

I have groovy script that builds a report from git log and git diff .  The purpose of the report is to review any third party plugins in the pom files before the build can be published so it is very crucial for report to be 100% accurate. The script basically takes a commit and retrieves all modified files since that commit and for each file I run git diff to get the added and removed lines.

For some reason one of the pom files that was added by cherry picking shows nothing when I do git diff on it.

**The command I use to get file names and their status is:**

```
git init -q&git remote add origin ssh://git@git.goldlnk.rootlnka.net/project/${gitRepos[i]}&git fetch origin ${branch} -q&git log ${lastRevs[i]}..origin/${branch} --name-status --pretty=format: --date-order --full-history -m --grep=Merge\\spull\\srequest.* --grep=Merge.*into.*/.* --grep=Automatic\\smerge\\sfrom.* --invert-grep -- ./*pom.xml
```

**then I run this command to get the diff:**

```
git checkout ${branch}&git diff --unified=0 --color=never ${lastRevs[i]} ${fileName}
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe the error was on my part. I was using wrong commitSHA in my command. I appreciate the answers though

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
git diff --name-only <sha of the starting commit> <sha of the commit you want to compare the starting commit with>
```

I hope that helps.